# commitment tier pricing plan with custom model

Tags: azure, azure-speech

Technical question - it's unclear from the Speech to Text pricing page ( https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/speech-services/#pricing ) if custom models are included in the commitment tier pricing plan.
I would be happy for clarification about that. thanks

Comment: If you use the resource above the quota provided, you will be charged for the additional usage as per the overage amount mentioned in the commitment tier.

Comment: It's unclear if there's no difference between regular or custom model. In the pay as you go there's some difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure pricing page only lists Standard Speech to Text in the commitment tiers. It does not list Custom Speech to Text as that is not available currently as a commitment tier.

Only the products available for Commitment Tier are listed.